# How to get the information about all running activities in the sytem?

Tags: android

I am developing an app related to ActivityManager.

I want to get information about all running activityies inside the system by using
ActivityManager.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **ActivityManger.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE)**

```
List<RunningTaskInfo> a=am.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Further use **PackageManager** to get the detail information about the task .

```
PackageManager pack=this.getPackageManager();
```

Finally iterate through the list of  RunningTaskInfo and get the info of each task :

```
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++){

    String packageName = a.get(i).topActivity.getPackageName();
    String appName= (String) pack.getApplicationLabel(pack.getApplicationInfo(packageName,PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
    Drawable d=pack.getApplicationIcon(packageName);

    Log.v("details"," "+packageName+" "+appName);    

    }
```

Need to add the permission in manifest file also

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
```

Hope this will help you.